# NewRelic::Agent::ServerConnectionException: Service unavailable (503): Service Unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

Configured New Relic with ruby on rails application, however newrelic_agent.log shows below error, server is on DigitalOcean.

```
INFO : Unable to send metric_data data, will try again later. Error: 
INFO : NewRelic::Agent::ServerConnectionException: Service unavailable (503): Service Unavailable
```

also seeing below

```
INFO : NewRelic::Agent::ServerConnectionException: Recoverable error connecting to collector-8.newrelic.com:443: Connection reset by peer
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a symptom of many different things. You should open a ticket with New Relic at https://support.newrelic.com

Answer (score 0):

Also check the status of the New Relic service to see if there is an outage on their side:
https://status.newrelic.com/